# "Unterricht" im Plural

Tags: grammatical-number, grammar-identification

Die Pluralform vom Wort *Unterricht* ist *Unterrichte*, nicht wahr? Im Gebrauch habe ich jedoch immer *Unterrichtsstunden* gehört (z. B. *Morgen haben wir drei Unterrichtsstunden*.) In welchen Kontexten wird dann *Unterrichte* verwendet?

Answer (score 4):

Im Deutschen ist es grundsätzlich erlaubt, Wörter zu "erfinden", sofern man den Regeln folgt. Insofern wäre "Unterrichte" tatsächlich der korrekte Plural. Im täglichen Sprachgebrauch wird das allerdings kein Mensch so sagen. Dort spricht man in der Regel von "Unterrichtsstunden" oder auch "Unterrichtseinheiten".

Bei manchen Wörtern macht der Plural im Deutschen nicht wirklich Sinn. Zum Beispiel: Verständnis, Willen, Aufregung … Man könnte durchaus jeweils einen Plural wie "Verständnisse, Willen (**!**), Aufregungen" bilden; jedoch nutzt man diese Wörter eher im Singular.

Vorstellbar wären Sätze wie **"Bei all den verschiedenen Verständnissen des Themas …"**, welche zwar grammatikalisch korrekt sind, jedoch so im Sprachgebrauch eher keine Anwendung finden.

Ein ähnliches Beispiel gibt es im Englischen mit dem Wort "information". Hier wird im Englischen auch stets der Singular verwendet.

Ich hoffe, das hilft dir etwas!

Answer (score 4):

«Unterrichtstunde» ist nicht dasselbe wie «Unterricht». Die Stunden sind problemlos zählbar. «Unterricht» hingegen bezeichnet eine Gesamtheit dessen, was unterrichtet wird. Typischerweise werden Gesamtheiten nicht gezählt, sondern gelten als eine Einheit. Es ist aber durchaus möglich, mehrere Gesamtheiten zu zählen, und dann wird das Wort durchaus im Plural verwendet, wie es dank neuen Hilfmitteln wie etwa einer [Google-Suche nach "die Unterrichte"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22die+unterrichte%22) leicht zu erkennen ist.

Answer (score 2):

Abgesehen davon, dass es grundsätzlich unüblich ist, nicht-abzählbare Mengen - oder *Gesamtheiten*, wie mach schreibt - in pluralisierter Form zu benutzen, kommt bei Unterricht(e) noch erschwerend hinzu, dass man dem Wort nicht sofort ansehen würde, was genau gemeint ist: Unterrichts*stunden* (bzw. *-einheiten*) oder aber Unterrichts*fächer*.